# How can I auto mount an encrypted internal drive on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, encryption, automount

I have a separate encrypted HDD which I would like to automatically mount when I login but the "Edit Mount Options..." is greyed out in Disks. How do I do this? Thank you.

[image]